# Thailand; relationship between defamation lawsuit and criminal defamation procedure

Tags: criminal-law, civil-law, thailand

Bangkok Post's

> The Sea View Resort released a five-page statement on Saturday after news of its legal action against Wesley Barnes attracted widespread attention. The statement was posted on the Twitter account of [Richard Barrow](https://twitter.com/RichardBarrow), a British expat travel blogger with 167,000 followers.
>
> Under Thailand’s tough criminal defamation laws, Mr Barnes could face up to two years in prison if found guilty.

The first paragraph seems to describe a civil lawsuit while the one that directly follows seems to describe a criminal issue.

While the results of, or thing brought to light by one might impact the other, my understanding is that in many countries these are separate processes.

**Question:** Is that also true in Thailand (with perhaps the sometimes perceived exception of it's [Lèse-majesté](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A8se-majest%C3%A9) law), or are they more closely linked so that the the second paragraph following the first is more than simply listing two related but different things?

I don't usually see "found guilty" in a discussion of a civil lawsuit.